# Why deque.append appears to be slower than list when performing extra calculations?

Tags: python, list, time, append, deque

As shown below, where I try to implement a memory with max length.

`a` uses a list that pops the first item when reaches the maximum length, `b` uses deque and relies on its built-in management of maxlen

```
import time
import numpy as np
import collections

a = [np.ones((64, 64), dtype=np.int64) + i for i in range(100000)]
b = collections.deque(a, maxlen=100000)
element = np.ones((64, 64), dtype=np.int64)

time.sleep(0.5)  # stimulates more initialization and preprocessing

t = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    temp = element * i - i  # stimulate some calculation on the fly
    b.append(temp)
print(time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    temp = element * i - i  # stimulate some calculation on the fly
    if len(a) == 100000:
        a.pop(0)
    a.append(temp)
print(time.time() - t)
print(len(a))
print(len(b))
```

**Expected**: `b` should take less time running since it has O(1) for popleft and append, while `a` has O(n) for popleft and O(1) for append. Since their stimulated calculation is the same, deque should take less time.

Surprisingly, it outputs this:

```
0.6613483428955078  # time for deque
0.24213624000549316  # time for list
100000  # check length and make sure they are doing what I want
100000
```

Even more surprisingly, if I remove the calculation `temp = element * i - i` for both implementations, the result changed significantly

```
0.0010280609130859375  # time for deque
0.16035985946655273  # time for list
100000
100000
```

What went wrong in the above code? Why do calculations unrelated to append make such a difference?

Comment: why are you timing calculations unrelated to what you are actually timing? also can't reproduce, w/ calcs deque is still a bit faster for me usually

Comment: @Matiiss Originally, I only tested append without calculation, and deque was faster than list as I expected. So to make sure nothing goes wrong when I put it into my program, I added the calculation to simulate what happens in my actual program. And I got this weird result, so I want to know what went wrong, and whether I should still use deque in my case

Comment: This is almost certainly due to allocation/deallocation costs or cache effects. Swap the order of the tests, and you should see the deque test run faster.

Comment: @user2357112 thank you so much! that solved my question, I didn't expect the allocation/deallocation costs or cache effects would make such a large difference. Swapping order does make deque faster than the list

Comment: Note that both the list and the deque hold references to your original batch of 100000 arrays. Once the arrays are removed from both data structures, their buffers can be reclaimed and recycled for new arrays. That happens in the second test you run, whichever that is.